# What does one put in emplace hint on unordered_multimap or unordered_map?

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, unordered-set

I know how `map::emplace_hint` works from reading the documentation, but how does `unordered_multimap::emplace_hint` works??

```
template <class... Args>
iterator emplace_hint ( const_iterator position, Args&&... args );
```

since this is a hashed container.. what should one put as `position` to optimize an in-place insertion??